# Angular 10: display user information on a view

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a page where I list all  my registered users and I want to create an action where I click on the user name and open another component to show infos from this specific users. I already create another component with name **user-details**. How the best way to do that? Maybe reading the ID from URL?

here is my code:

**users.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-users',
  templateUrl: './manage-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-users.component.scss']
})
export class ManageUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = firestore.collection('users').valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
```

**users.component.html**

```
<div class="card card-custom example example-compact gutter-b">    
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Actions</th>
          <th scope="col">Sign-up Time</th>
          <th scope="col">Username</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Is Enabled</th>
          <th scope="col">Is Online</th>
          <th scope="col">Last Time Online</th>
          <th scope="col">Age</th>
          <th scope="col">Gender</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          
          <tr *ngFor="let item of items | async">
              <td>
                <div ngbDropdown container="body">
                  <button class="btn" ngbDropdownToggle>Actions</button>
                  <div ngbDropdownMenu>
                    <button ngbDropdownItem>View</button>
                    <button ngbDropdownItem>Block</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <button ngbDropdownItem>Delete</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
    
              <td>{{item.createdDate}}</td>
              <td><a target="_blank" href="/user-details">{{item.name}}</a></td>
              <td>{{item.email}}</td>
              <td>{{item.isEnabled}}</td>
              <td>{{item.online}}</td>
              <td>{{item.last_time_online}}</td>
              <td>{{item.birthday}}</td>
              <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you would need to pass the unique identifier to the user-details page. ex. href="/user-details/{{item.id}}"

Comment: You can do this in many ways, 
`i) pass in url`
`ii) set on click in the localStorage`
`iii) use @Input to pass the id to the child component.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the user id as URL parameter to the user like this

```html
<a href="/user-details/{{item.id}}" class="btn btn-link">John Mike</a>
```

And get thet id parameter in the user-details component using **ActivatedRoute**

```js
  constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // No Subscription
    this.snapshotParam = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");

  }
```

Refer example below

[Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-url-parameters)

Comment: Thank you! Once I do that, how I gonna read the user infos on another view? Something like {{ snapshotParam.name }} ?

Comment: @FernandoAureliano So you will get just the id from the snapshotParam based on the ID you can query your database to fetch the details.

Comment: I follow the code example in the most simple way, but its not working on my project with the route /manage-users. I change this line this.router.navigate(["animals", animal]); to this.router.navigate(["manage-users/animals", animal]); and still not work

Comment: It works get the parameters, but when I tried const user = firestore.collection('users').doc(this.snapshotParam); I cant get parameters from user inside this constant. I got the error: Cannot find name 'firestore'.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

- Cache your users in a service, so that you can retrieve them from it by id:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UserCacheService {
  getUserById(): User {
    // Naive approach, you of course have to think about asynchronicity and error handling here.
    return this.users[id];
  }
}
```

- You route to the details component using the id.

Define the route like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'users/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },
];
```

Then when you route to it, you can get the id from the url like this:

```
// You can e.g. do this in ngOnInit.
const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
// Think about what happens when someone opens the url while the user is not already cached!
const user = this.userCacheService.getUserById(id);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I did it and I got a error: TS1005: ';' expected.  getUserById: User {

Comment: Thanks!! Now the page loads with param on url, but I cant read the params, I got the error: Cannot find name 'id'. My URL is /user-details/:id Should I change the param line return this.users[id]; ?

Comment: I put on the view: <p>USER: {{ user }}</p>
  <p>ID: {{ id }}</p>

Comment: I'm getting the error: Property 'activatedRoute' does not exist on type 'UserDetailsComponent'. and Property 'userCacheService' does not exist on type 'UserDetailsComponent'.

Comment: I'm importing on user-details.component: import {userCacheService} from './user-cache.service';